# An integral of a complementary error function

Tags: integration, special-functions

I really appreciate it if someone help me solving this integral:

$$ \int \frac 1x \cdot \operatorname{Erfc}^n x\, dx,$$

where $\operatorname{Erfc}$ is the [complementary error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), defined as $\operatorname{Erfc}=\frac 2{\sqrt \pi}\int_x^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}dt$.

thank you

Comment: What $n$? What makes you think a primitive exists, involving only usual functions?

Comment: Is $n$ an integer? Real? Complex?! You really should be specific...

Comment: n is a real number

Comment: Do you need the indefinite integral (as stated), or the definite integral, e.g., from 0 to $\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

A Taylor series at $x=0$ may be found [here](http://tinyurl.com/cepj23v):
$$
\int \frac{\text{Erfc}^n(x)}{x}dx=\log(x)-\frac{2nx}{\sqrt{\pi}}+\frac{(n-1)nx^2}{\pi}+\cdots
$$
There is also a result for $n=1$ given: $\log(x)-\frac{2x}{\sqrt{\pi}}{ _2F_2}\left(1/2,1/2;3/2,3/2;-x^2\right)$.

**EDIT:**
You get a series expansion for $\text{Erfc}^n(x)$ at $x=\infty$ [here](http://tinyurl.com/cywxvyt):
$$
\text{Erfc}(x)^n=\left(1-2 \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k x^{2 k+1}}{\sqrt{\pi }(2 k+1) k!}\right){}^n
$$

Comment: thank u draks.but i need a simpler answer if it exists

Comment: @davood So let me quote Didier: *What makes you think a primitive exists, involving only usual functions?*

Comment: yes you are right.but of course i have to integrate it from a known value to infinity. in this way a series expansion at x=0 is not allowed to use. do i have another choice?

Comment: @davood you can try [this](http://tinyurl.com/d8owgjq)...

Comment: @davood: [There](http://tinyurl.com/d9e7jsg) are series expansions at $x=\infty$.

Comment: @davood, you're welcome.